# does vimdiff support merging diffs

Tags: vim, vimdiff

Can vimdiff support a merge of diffs that are on the same line (so that I get the aggregate of them?)

example: starting with the following conflict markers:

```
I
like
apples
peaches
<<<<<<< HEAD
bananas
=======
cherries
>>>>>>> diverge
for supper
```

in the example above, can I use the `do` and `dp` commands to actually merge the diffs, or can I only end up with one of the other?
put another way, If I'd like to end up with

```
I
like
apples
peaches
bananas
cherries
for supper
```

then can I do this with diffpush and get, or do I have to drop back to basic vim commands to select the hunks to merge? as `bananas` and `cherries` are on the same line, diffget and push can control which I pick, but I dont seem to be able to have both and merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without a plugin/mapping. By default, you will need to resort to normal editing commands.

It looks like the "Splice" plugin ( https://github.com/sjl/splice.vim ) provides mappings to select hunks from multiple files; I haven't used it though so it may not work the way I assume.

Comment: This looks like pretty much what i need,  and thanks for confirmation that vanilla vimdiff doesn't do what i nees

Comment: @phatmanace Did you end up figuring how to use both hunks using splice? I can't be able to do it.

Comment: @Michael, I wasted hours trying to make splice work and gave up... AFAICT, the author could not care less about responding to t installation / usage [github issues](https://github.com/sjl/splice.vim/issues)